# While moving from one Fragment to another, SwipeRefreshLayout is being copied to another Fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I have `SwipeRefreshLayout` in `Fragment A`. I switch to `Fragment B` from `Fragment A` but in `Fragment B` also i get a `SwipeRefreshLayout` which i do not want. Please explain why is this happening and what can i do to fix this?

**Transition**

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("deviceId", deviceId);
fragment.setArguments(args);
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.rlConfiguration, fragment).commit();
```

**Fragment A**

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/srlConfiguration"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlConfiguration"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".ui.viewlist.ViewlistFragment">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvFilter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_button"
            android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
            android:paddingVertical="4dp"
            android:text="All Trackers"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivFilter"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/filter" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:background="@color/gray" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            tools:visibility="visible" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="@string/empty_list_text" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

**Fragment B**

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:fillViewport="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            tools:context=".ui.module.ModuleFragment">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Configure your Module Data here: "
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20dp" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Accelerometer Sensor"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/module_acc_sensor"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:entries="@array/module_config_list"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
                    android:textColorHint="#6B7999" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Temperature Sensor"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/module_temp_sensor"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:entries="@array/module_config_list"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
                    android:textColorHint="#6B7999" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Humidity Sensor"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/module_humidity_sensor"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:entries="@array/module_config_list"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
                    android:textColorHint="#6B7999" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Wi-Fi Module"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/module_wifi"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:entries="@array/module_config_list"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
                    android:textColorHint="#6B7999" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Location Tracking Module"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/module_location_tracking"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:entries="@array/module_network_list"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
                    android:textColorHint="#6B7999" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Protocol Select"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/module_protocol_select"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:entries="@array/module_config_list"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
                    android:textColorHint="#6B7999" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="No Coverage Functionality"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/module_no_coverage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:entries="@array/module_config_list"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
                    android:textColorHint="#6B7999" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="BLE Functionality"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/module_ble_functionality"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:entries="@array/module_config_list"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
                    android:textColorHint="#6B7999" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Tilt Functionality"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/module_tilt_functionality"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:entries="@array/module_config_list"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
                    android:textColorHint="#6B7999" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Motion State Change Interrupt"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/module_motion_state_change"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:entries="@array/motion_state_change"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
                    android:textColorHint="#6B7999" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Fall Detection Interrupt"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/module_fall_det_int"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:entries="@array/module_config_list"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
                    android:textColorHint="#6B7999" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Tilt Interrupt"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/module_tilt_int"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:entries="@array/module_config_list"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
                    android:textColorHint="#6B7999" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Low Battery"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/module_low_batteryt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:entries="@array/module_config_list"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
                    android:textColorHint="#6B7999" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Temperature Interrupt"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/module_temp_inter"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:entries="@array/module_config_list"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
                    android:textColorHint="#6B7999" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Humidity Interrupt"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/module_humidity_inter"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:entries="@array/module_config_list"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
                    android:textColorHint="#6B7999" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Box Open Functionality"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
                android:paddingVertical="11dp">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spTheftAlert"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:entries="@array/disable_enable_list"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
                    android:textColorHint="#6B7999" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Flight Mode"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
                android:paddingVertical="11dp">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spFlightMode"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:entries="@array/disable_enable_list"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
                    android:textColorHint="#6B7999" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/switchExtended"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Extended Mode" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDeviceIdHeading"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Device Id"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/module_deviceid_EditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/layerdevice"
                android:drawablePadding="20dp"
                android:hint="Device Id"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
                android:paddingVertical="10dp"
                android:textColorHint="#6B7999"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/computeModuleButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_button"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/moduleBtnLabel"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/module_verticalTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share the code for `onCreateView` for both Fragments. Also for FragmentB you should consider using `ConstraintLayout` in xml, it will reduce the nesting in xml and easier to manage/read.

Comment: I dont think `onCreateView` has anything to do with this.

Comment: Show how you transition from A to B.

Comment: @dominicoder Updated Please check.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "In Fragment B also I get a SwipeRefreshLayout". Do you mean that the layout is literally in the view hierarchy when you inspect it with the layout manager or do you mean you still see the refresh indicator when transitioning to B, if it was shown while still in A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/transactions#add-remove
You should understand where your new fragment will be hosted.

You change A fragment to B but into RelativeLayout. I think you should wrap SwipeRefreshLayout into FrameLayout with id frRoot and into replace() specify R.id.frRoot.